# How to emulate a datagridview ColumnDividerDoubleClick

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, datagridview

As we know when a column divider is double clicked the column width resizes itself to fit its contents. How can we emulate this behavior with code?

Answer (score 1):

[AutoResizeColumn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms158583%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) method:

```
dataGridView.AutoResizeColumn(columnIndex,
                              DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells);
```

[AutoResizeColumns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms158593%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) to resize all columns at once.

Comment: Setting AutoResizeColumn to AllCells locks the column width and disables resizing which defeats the purpose. I want to fit column width to its content without locking the columns resizing ability hence the double click column divider is just what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Add an event handler for the [ColumnDividerDoubleClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.columndividerdoubleclick%28v=vs.90%29.aspx#Y114) event of the DataGridView object, and include a call to the [AutoResizeColumn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms158583%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) method, passing the column index as an argument:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_ColumnDividerDoubleClick(sender as Object, _
        e as DataGridViewColumnDividerDoubleClickEventArgs) _
        Handles DataGridView1.ColumnDividerDoubleClick

    If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then
        DataGridView1.AutoResizeColumn(e.ColumnIndex)
    End If

End Sub
```

The AutoResizeColumn method is not to be confused with the [AutoSizeColumnsMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.autosizecolumnsmode%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)
property which is used to let the DataGridView control take charge of resizing
columns on the behalf the user. When using
the event handler above, this property should be set to 
`DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.None` (which is the default).